# Creating a sphinx extension involving a directive that takes in arguments

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I am relatively new to writing sphinx extensions and would like to create one that takes in a number of keywords that are provided alongside the directive name inside the rst document and replaces it with a block of html.

The predefined list-table directive in docutils allows to do it as following:

```
.. list-table::

   * - item1

     - item2
   
     - item3
```

So far, I have only taken a look at the [provided helloworld example](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/helloworld.html), which replaces the directive keyword with the string "Hello World".

My idea is to instead return a `.. raw::` html tag alongside the html i would like to insert. Is there a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sphinx-jinja-ext](https://github.com/kleynjan/sphinx-jinja-ext), a minimal Sphinx directive I wrote recently.

It defines a directive where the 'arguments' you mention are passed as node content:

```
.. jinja_div:: 

   var1 var2
```

resulting in this html:

```
<div class="jinja">
  {{ var1 var2 }}
</div>
```

It should be simple to adapt [jinja.py](https://github.com/kleynjan/sphinx-jinja-ext/blob/main/jinja.py) in that project to your requirements.

In general, it helps to be aware that rST gets mapped to a docutils doctree first, which is then translated to HTML.